# How do I modify a browser tab's text styling with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, tabs, text-styling

I am trying to write a bit of code in a script that changes the color and/or text formatting of a browser's tab--any tab, not just the currently selected one--when a given process completes, so that I can tell, without tabbing back to said tab, if the process is finished or not.

What I'm looking for is the specific bit of code or call to make that accesses the tab's style (or whatever); something where I could go

```
tabWhereScriptFinishedExecution.style.color("#77ffa5");
tabWhereScriptFinishedExecution.style.fontWeight("bold");
```

or something. Tab Mix Plus and its different effects on the tabs reflecting various states and whatnot were what got me thinking about this.

I'm using Firefox, and working this into a Greasemonkey script, so I'd like to avoid using JQuery if possible.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it is not possible to do the way you are trying to achieve it. You cannot style the tab text. It is part of the browser. Tab Mix Plus you are referring to is a plug in for Firefox.